# enum vs text data type in posgresql performance

Tags: postgresql, performance, enums

I have a column in postgresql that is a text data type. But it really holds always 4 kind of values, these are:

```
EOS,EOS in 6 months,EOS in 12 months, EOS in 24 months
```

I always perform the same kind of query which will depend on user input but it will contain one or more of those values above, as such:

```
select * from table
where text_column in 
('EOS','EOS in 6 months','EOS in 12 months', 'EOS in 24 months')
```

I wonder if I transform the data type from text to enum whether I will get any performance benefit?

Comment: If it's an enum go for enum.

Comment: It might make sense not to use an enum but just store the number of months til EOS, i.e. `0`, `6`, `12` or `24`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if I transform the data type from text to enum whether I will get any performance benefit?

Yes, you will - demonstrably so. [Here's an example benchmark](https://dbfiddle.uk/zPuRn3Za) on a 100k sample:

| variant | avg execution time - lower is better |
| --- | --- |
| enum column with index | 00:00:00.174101 |
| text column with index | 00:00:00.193802 |
| enum column without index | 00:00:00.20623 |
| text column without index | 00:00:00.299419 |

Under the hood, [`enum` taking 4 bytes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html#DATATYPE-ENUM-IMPLEMENTATION-DETAILS) is just lighter and therefore easier to process and handle than full-[`text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER)-based labels taking up (1|4)+length-compression. I assume you have one already, but in case you don't, you can also see that adding an [index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) helps more than changing type and the two can work together.

If you want to go further space wise, you can go down to 2 bytes if you instead use a dictionary table with a [`smallint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC) primary key, or single-character `text`/`char`. From there, you can go even further and do what PostgreSQL does internally and use [1-byte `"char"`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-SPECIAL-TABLE) (not the same as `char` or `char(1)`). The downside is that it requires joins and lookups to query based on textual representation of a label, which can be inconvenient or even break compatibility.

You might also want to dump this labelling entirely and replace the field with a precise [`timestamptz`/`date`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) when the thing is supposed to get End-Of-S(ervice?) status, or an `interval` if this label dictates the EOS moment based on another field, like a `purchase_date`, `created_at`, `subscription_start`, `premiere_date`.

Answer (score 3):

The only foolproof answer here would be "you'll need to benchmark it".

Having said that, if you **only** text this column for equality (remember  that the `in` operator is just a fancy way of writing multiple equality tests) and you a limited number of valid values for that column, it makes sense to use an enum - the values are shorter (a single integer value vs a longer string), so it would store more compactly, leading to more efficient disk reads.

TL;DR - using an enum is probably a good idea here, but you should benchmark it.

Answer (score 1):

ENUM is encoded as 4 bytes so you will save a few bytes.

Performance should be a tiny bit faster but nothing spectacular.

You will be able to specify the sorting order at ENUM creation time, this is useful because text sorts alphabetically so '6 months' is after '24 months' because '6'>'2'... it's more intuitive.

And the most important, if you didn't define a constraint on the TEXT field, then there's no guarantee the column only contains one of the allowed values. If there is a bug in the application it could insert anything. ENUM will ensure the column only contains one of the allowed values.

Comment: Enum types are `real` floating point numbers internally.

Comment: Really? That's a bit of a weird choice...

Comment: Think of `ALTER TYPE name ADD VALUE new_enum_value [ { BEFORE | AFTER } neighbor_enum_value ]`. It is impossible to add an integer between 1 and 2, but it is simple to add a floating point number between 1.0 and 2.0.